# Lambda expression compilation (== and equal with char)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lambda

Comparing char type variables using `==` and `Equals` in expression produce different SQL queries in NHibernate and cause wrong (optimized?) behavior.

I build filter expression like this:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildFilter<T>(char firstLetter) where T : IEntity
{
    return PredicateBuilder
        .True<T>()
        .And(ft => ft.FirstLetter.Equals(firstLetter));
}
```

and use it like this:

`Session.Query<T>().Where(filter)`

If i compare char with `.Equals` it produce next query:

```
2017-03-23 12:02:52,499 [10] DEBUG NHibernate.SQL - 

select tag0_.Id as col_0_0_ 
  from [ft].[Tags] tag0_ 
 where @p0=1 and tag0_.FirstLetter=@p1 
order by tag0_.Title asc;@p0 = True 

[Type: Boolean (0:0:0)], @p1 = 'А' [Type: StringFixedLength (4000:0:0)]
```

and as you could see, NHibernate made FirstLetter variable sql parameter (@p1) and that's correct.

**Problem**:

Previously, i used comparison with `==` operator like this:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildFilter<T>(char firstLetter) where T : IEntity
{
    return PredicateBuilder
        .True<T>()
        .And(ft => ft.FirstLetter == firstLetter);
}
```

and that produces me next query:

```
2017-03-23 12:17:22,718 [23] DEBUG NHibernate.SQL - 

select tag0_.Id as col_0_0_ 
  from [ft].[Tags] tag0_ 
 where @p0=1 
   and tag0_.FirstLetter='А' 
order by tag0_.Title asc;@p0 = True 

[Type: Boolean (0:0:0)]
```

This query looks correct too.

But, just one moment... Each call of method with `==` comparison will produce **the same query** with `tag0_.FirstLetter='А'` predicate, it doesn't care about real char value that was used in filter expression!

That's look like NHibernate cache or something like that?

Comment: It wouldn't be the first bug discovered in NHibernate :-) If you can make a unit test describing it, you can submit it.

Comment: @xanatos i still not pretty sure about reason of this bug (or feature?), could it be cache strategy or anything else

Comment: Just to be sure: if you execute var `res1 = Session.Query<T>().Where(BuildFilter<T>('A').List(); var res2 = Session.Query<T>().Where(BuildFilter<T>('B').List();` in truth NH will execute two queries with `FirstLetter = 'A'`?

Comment: @xanatos, yes. I've tested it another way and got next results: `{ "signEqualA": [ 34, 35, 36, 37, 38 ], "signEqualB": [ 34, 35, 36, 37, 38 ], "methodEqualA": [ 34, 35, 36, 37, 38 ], "methodEqualB": [ 40, 41, 42, 43, 44 ] }`. Just to clarify, signEqual means `==`, methodEqual means `.Equal`. Usage of `==` ignore next call variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3247). You may be able to call `.ToString()` on the `char` property and supply the literal value as a string for dodging the bug, but I am not sure.

Its root lies in some .Net compilation rule causing `char` to be converted to `int` in lambda expression.

Currently fixed in master branch (upcoming v5), I do not know if it may get back-ported to v4.